# Is it possible to make different click event for mat-checkbox and mat-checkbox label?

Tags: angular-material2, angular7

I need to have different click events for mat-checkbox and its label. Anyone help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to accomplish this.

Place your tag text in a `span` and use `(click)` for the `span`, and `(change)` for the `mat-checkbox`

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="SetString('CheckBox')"></mat-checkbox>
<span style="margin-left:2%" (click)="SetString('CheckBoxTag')">Click here for tag event!</span>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1pgeg?embed=1&file=app/checkbox-overview-example.html